# Setting overlapping x_label and y_label on Seaborn FacetGrid

Tags: python, facet, seaborn

The Seaborn examples for FacetGrids all contain independent labels for each row and column.  e.g.:

[image: http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/_images/many_facets.png]

Is it possible to generate a single label for all the rows, or all the columns of the FacetGrid as in this ggplot example:
[image: http://blog.yhathq.com/static/img/figures/diamonds_facet_grid_point.png]

Comment: For additional clarity, the y-labels I am referring to are "position" in the Seaborn example and "price" in the ggplot example.  The respective x-labels are "step" and "carat".

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/faceted_histogram.html

Comment: No, I was hoping to add a single y-axis, like "price", so the y-axis isn't so cluttered.  I am using secondary y-axis labels as in the link you provided.